# executing jquery function using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tried to execute a jquery function using a  tag. first of all I tried like this.

```
<a href="#about_us" onclick="aboutus()">About US</a>
```

and this is my jquery function in separate file.

```
function aboutus() {

    $("#content").css({
        "display": "block",
        "opacity" : 1
    });

    $(".about_us_one").css({
        "left": ($w - 980) / 2,
        "top": 120,
        "z-index": 1000,
        "display": "block"
    });

    $(".about_us_one").animate({
        "opacity": 0.90,
        "width": 980
    }, 2500, $easing2, function() {
    });
    var $about_us_one, $contentHeight;

    $about_us_one = $(".about_us_one").height();
    $(".about_us_two").css({
        "left": ($w - 980) / 2,
        "top": 140 + $about_us_one,
        "z-index": 1000,
        "display": "block"
    });

    $(".about_us_two").animate({
        "opacity": 0.90,
        "width": 980
    }, 2500, $easing2, function() {
    });

    $contentHeight = $(document).height();
    $("#bfooter").animate({
        "top": $contentHeight,
        "margnin-top": 15
    });

    $("#splash").animate({
        "top": 0,
        "opacity": 0.75,
        "height": 100
    }, 1500, $easing2, function() {
    });

    $(".menu").animate({
        "opacity": 1,
        "top": 50,
        //"margin-top": 50
        // "height": $h
    }, 500, $easing);

    $("#slogn1").animate({
        "opacity": 1,
        "top": 50,
        //"margin-top": 50
        // "height": $h
    }, 500, $easing);
    $("#slogn2").animate({
        "opacity": 1,
        "top": 20,
        //"margin-top": 50
        // "height": $h
    }, 500, $easing);
}
```

when using this method every thing works fine. but if I refresh the page. then I must click again that about us link to view the contents.

so this is not the thing I really need to do. so I tried to pass a variable from the  tag using php like this.

```
<a href="http://localhost/eventztable/home.php?name=about_us">About US</a>

$page = $_GET['name'];
        if ($page == "about_us") {
            ?>
            <script>
                aboutus();
            </script>
            <?php
        }
```

but in this method nothing is happening. so I think there should be a problem. so I put an alert("test") in my about us function. but when refreshing that alert is popping out. but other codes are not executing.

I'am really really tired of doing this and that. please help me on this. if there is any easy way please tell me.

thank you..

Answer (score 2):

Consider this as an example:

```
<a href="#aboutus" onclick="aboutus()">About Us</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function aboutus() {
    alert(123);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash == '#aboutus') {
        $('a[href="#aboutus"]').trigger('click');
    }
});
</script>
```

After clicking the link (initial click). Of course, it will execute, then when you it detects the hash (in this case `#aboutus`), it will execute again, (in this case, the `alert()` inside the `aboutus()` function)

Comment: I don't know why. i just use your code. nothing changed. but only i click on the link it shows 123. nothing when refresh

Comment: this is just an example, you can just adjust it according to your code. no big differences anyway

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without looking at all your HTML but since your javascript is editing the CSS of elements, its possible you are calling the function to edit the CSS before the elements are even rendered. Try changing to run the function when everything is rendered.

```
$page = $_GET['name'];
        if ($page == "about_us") {
            ?>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){ 
                    aboutus();
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
```

Comment: @Joel- nothing happens. do i need to put my jquery function also inside document ready ?

Comment: No you shouldn't have to. This document ready function waits until everything has loaded before firing. Do you have any errors in your console? I think we'll need more of your code.

Comment: After seeing kevinabelitas example, I think it is much more appropriate. It removes the need for php in this context. If his solution doesnt work there is something else wrong in your code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

On load You need to trigger click event

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['name'];
        if ($page == "about_us") {
            ?>
            <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#about_us').trigger('click');

    });
 $( "#about_us" ).on( "click", function() {
      aboutus();
    });
</script>
            <?php
        } ?>
```

Comment: no errors sir. only alert is popping out. other codes are just escaping. i don't know wy. and that also working only when i remove document.ready in the php code

Comment: did you replace your code with this code , is alert() still there in your code? please clear cache if needed

Comment: yes i put alert again in to the code. sir. I tried by clearing the cache also.

Comment: I can thing there could be error on my jquery function but the case is when i use onlick event on my <a></a> tag this code is running without any errors. so there should no errors in jquery. only thing is it is not executing the code when i restart